# Connect to Discovered Bluetooth devices using Android Using MAC Address from ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, bluetooth

I'm new to Bluetooth Development in Android.

Somehow I managed to get the searched devices and they are discovered and listed in a ListView.

So far So Good.
Now I want to connect to the devices which are listed in the ListView.

I searched a lot, and got many results but I understood none.
Does anybody know how to connect as you click the ListView item ?
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation, probably the code that I've found refers to old apis because none works to connect to a device. I've managed to connect to a bt device only entering the mac code by myself programmatically, i need to connect through a popup asking which device to connect to.